# MySql error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to retrieve my data from MySQL to be used in python. But it prints out `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` The server log shows that `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
This is [the server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aObj.jpg) . Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
This is the python code

```
import pandas as pd

user, pw, host, db = 'root', '12345', '127.0.0.1', 'ca2database'
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
df= pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM student', con=cnx)
print(df)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

and this is the [data in the sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYE59.jpg)

Comment: thanks for answering, i have updated the code and show picture of the data in sql

Comment: So you are connecting `localhost` yet the arg passed equals `127.0.0.1`? The MySQL security for `root` is host part specific usually so this may matter. Outside of the Python connection, can you access the MySQL instance as root and check security to see how it is configured? I'd guess your `pw` arg is null too. Unfortunately I don't know `pandas` very well either.

Comment: I just tried ```cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='12345', host='localhost', database='ca2database')``` But it still produces the same output. And i need the ' quotation if not it will say the variable is not defined.

Comment: The thing is it was working fine a week ago, but then i executed it again this morning and it returns nonetype error.

Comment: Here's an example of a way I've run MySQL queries on Windows machines using Python sort of how you are doing it.... https://pastebin.com/SkkfKvbu Although it is a dumbed down version and I'm sure I should be closing the cursor too so obviously it'll need fine tuned and tested more. Here's a reference link I used to build the logic if my notes are accurate: https://ianhowson.com/blog/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python/. Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and see if that makes any difference. Also, try all variations of those values with double quotes rather than single quotes too.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I don't think the error is from my python code as the code is given by my lecturer and other student is able to use it without a problem. I have consulted my lecturer and she seems to suggest that there might be a bug in the MySQL side.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between 'localhost', '%' and '127.0.0.1'. Seems than Python use socket to connect to the database and '%' is preferred.

Add the following root variation (or just grant your database):

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<your password>';    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```